# For loop with two matrices: The resulting matrices are different in size from the input matrix data

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

Maybe this is a silly question but here we go:

I have two input matrices of 5X6 in a two for loop where I have a simulation in simulink that has to be run for each combination in order to get two resulting matrices but with the size of 6x6 having issues at then end to get my contour plots since the size are different. I have tried with size(max()), length, numel and the results are different from each, but always the size are different. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

The code looks like this so far (battery_bankmatrix_test1 and power_peak_PVmatrix_1test are my input matrices of 5x6 and results_waterproduction and results_energyconsumption are the resulting matrices of 6x6)

```
for i_Batterycapacity = 1:length(battery_bankmatrix_test1)

     for i_PVarray = 1:length(power_peak_PVmatrix_1test)
         parameter.battery.cap = battery_bankmatrix_test1(i_Batterycapacity); 
         parameter.pv.power = power_peak_PVmatrix_1test(i_PVarray); %Watt peak, used to run the simulation          
         % Calculate solar radiation on surface and run Simulink simulation
         % load PV data    
         %load PV data    
         % load('PV Data/PV U-V Map SolarWorld 150Wp Poly - 4 Parameter Model based on Carrero et al 2010.mat');  
         PVmodule_data = 'PV U-V Map SolarWorld 150Wp Poly - 4 Parameter Model based on Carrero et al 2010.mat';
         load([cd '\PV Data\' PVmodule_data]);
         % Calculate solar radiation on surface and run Simulink simulation
         run('Revived_SIM_Manual.p');
         sim('B_Simulink_Sim_Revived_V2_July2017');
         % % saveas(ho,sprintf('FIG%d.png')); % will create FIG1, FIG2,...
         % 
         results_waterproduction(i_PVarray,i_Batterycapacity) = water_production(8760)
         results_energyconsumption(i_PVarray,i_Batterycapacity) = consumption(8760)
     end 
 end
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there's nothing in that code block that _we_ could debug.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that the results aren't the same because **numel** return the number of element `5x6 = 30`, the function **length** returns the maximum of lines or columns, here it returns `6` (because your matrix is 5x6, but if it was 6x11, length will return 11) and the last one is `size(max())` it returns `1` because the maximum is only one element but if you try `max(size())` instead it will return 6.

Comment: That means my code is not wrong per se. Thanks for explaining the difference between the comands. But what could you recommend me to plot the contour from my input matrices of 5X6 and my matrix of 6X6? I am bit stocked there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by ''*the contour from my input matrices*'' ?

Comment: I meant after running the loops I get two matrices of 6x6 as a result and I want to make 2 contour plots having X and Y the 5x6 matrices and Z one of the 6x6 matrices, but since the dimensions are different I cannot do it. Is it more clear what i meant? Sorry, my English is not perfect.